# Defining a macro with combine many options to one bracket

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I am beginner in writing macros with multi options. What I want to do, is to combine many options to one pair of brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\def\DLineS{%
\@ifnextchar[%
 {\DLineS@i}
 {\DLineS@i[1.25]}%
}
\def\DLineS@i[#1]{%
\@ifnextchar[%
 {\DLineS@ii{#1}}
 {\DLineS@ii{#1}[-0.25]}%
}
\def\DLineS@ii#1[#2]#3#4{%
\draw[latex-latex] ($(#3)!#2!(#4)$) -- ($(#3)!#1!(#4)$) 
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $A$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $B$}] (B) at (1,1);
\filldraw (A) circle (1.5pt);
\filldraw (B) circle (1.5pt);
\DLineS[1.5][-0.75]{A}{B};
% I want this line is \DLineS[1.5,-0.75]{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to have a macro with two options? or just the splitting of the first `[,]` ?

Comment: Maybe `\DLineS[a]{A}{B}`->`\DLineS@ii{a}[-.25]{A}{B}` while `\DLineS[a,b]{A}{B}`->`\DLineS@ii{a}[b]{A}{B}`. But `\DLineS[a]{A}{B}`->`\DLineS@ii{a}[1-a]{A}{B}` also makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to play with `\def` unless you know what you are doing. If so, you can do the following. Otherwise consider egreg's answer using `xparse`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\def\DLineS{\@ifnextchar[%
    {\DLineS@i}{\DLineS@i[1.25]}}
\def\DLineS@i[#1]{\@ifnextchar[%
    {\DLineS@ii{#1}}{\DLineS@iii#1,;}}
\def\DLineS@ii#1[#2]#3#4{%
    \draw[latex-latex]($(#3)!#2!(#4)$)--($(#3)!#1!(#4)$)}
\def\DLineS@iii#1,#2;#3#4{\def\temp{#2}\ifx\temp\empty%
        \DLineS@ii#1[-.25]{#3}{#4}\else\DLineS@iv[#1][#2]{#3}{#4}\fi}
\def\DLineS@iv[#1][#2,]{\DLineS@ii#1[#2]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $A$}](A)at(0,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $B$}](B)at(1,1);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $C$}](C)at(2,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $D$}](D)at(3,1);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $E$}](E)at(4,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $F$}](F)at(5,1);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $G$}](G)at(6,0);
    \coordinate[label=below:{\small $H$}](H)at(7,1);
    \filldraw(A)circle(1.5pt)(B)circle(1.5pt)(C)circle(1.5pt)(D)circle(1.5pt)(E)circle(1.5pt)(F)circle(1.5pt)(G)circle(1.5pt)(H)circle(1.5pt);
    \DLineS[1.5][-0.75]{A}{B};
    \DLineS[1.5,-0.75]{C}{D};
    \DLineS[1.5]{E}{F};
    \DLineS{G}{H};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is good solution. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DLineS}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}O{1.25,-0.25}mm}{%
  % no optional argument is like calling [1.25,-0.25]
  \DLineSaux#1{#2}{#3}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DLineSaux}{mmmm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
    {\DLineSaux{#1}{-0.25}{#3}{#4}}% no comma in the optional argument, use -0.25
    {\draw[latex-latex] ($(#3)!#2!(#4)$) -- ($(#3)!#1!(#4)$)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $A$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $B$}] (B) at (1,1);
\filldraw (A) circle (1.5pt);
\filldraw (B) circle (1.5pt);
\DLineS[1.5,-0.75]{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $A$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $B$}] (B) at (1,1);
\filldraw (A) circle (1.5pt);
\filldraw (B) circle (1.5pt);
\DLineS{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $A$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{\small $B$}] (B) at (1,1);
\filldraw (A) circle (1.5pt);
\filldraw (B) circle (1.5pt);
\DLineS[1.5]{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

We do three steps; in the first step we just pass control to `\DLineSaux` after splitting the optional argument at the comma; if no optional argument is given, `[1.25,-0.25]` is passed; if just the first part is present (see third example), `xparse` passes `-NoValue-` to the next stage, so in this case we simply recall `\DLineSaux` with `-0.25` as the second argument.

[image]

Comment: @eqreg: Thanks so much for your advice. This is basic knowledge for me in the future. I don't want other package (xparse).

Comment: @eqreg:I do not understand how to use the command `\DlineSaux`.

Comment: @somkiat_t You *don't* use it explicitly; it is just an auxiliary command run by `\DLineS`.